# ng-options sected attribute is not working

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-4 control-label" for="gcAttribute">GC</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8"> 
        <select class="form-control" id="gcAttribute" ng-selected="selectedAttribute.GC" ng-model="selectedAttribute.GC" ng-options="item as item.ColumnName for item in tableColumns | filter:{TableName:'GC'}"></select>
        <textarea>{{selectedAttribute.GC|json}}</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

My options are populated but not the selection. I believe I am doing some thing which is not very easy to figure out.

I have an object called `selectedAttribute` which I want to edit, it has lots of properties `GC`, `PE`, `SL`

`GC`, `PE` and `SL` are some sort of Array like below in one object `tableColumns`

```
{{TableName:"GC", ColumnName="IdeaName" ..............}

{TableName:"PE", ColumnName="PresenterId" ............}

{TableName:"SL", ColumnName="VenueId" ..............}}
```

whilst editing I need a combobox with the seleted option on the object I can get the options bit fine but the selected option is not getting selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solved my issue with the ng-options

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-lg-4 control-label" for="gcAttribute">GC</label>
<div class="col-lg-8"> 
    <select class="form-control" id="gcAttribute" ng-selected="selectedAttribute.GC" ng-model="selectedAttribute.GC" ng-options="item.ColumnName as item.ColumnName for item in tableColumns | filter:{TableName:'GC'}"></select>
    <textarea>{{selectedAttribute.GC|json}}</textarea>
</div>
</div>
```

the key string was

```
item.ColumnName as item.ColumnName
```

and also I could see the result like this.

```
<option value="string:IdeaName" label="IdeaName">IdeaName</option>
<option value="string:IdeaSector" label="IdeaSector">IdeaSector</option>
```

hopefully helps some one

and the selection also works, Thanks to JB for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `ng-selected` attribute on the [select directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

To make one of the options selected, you don't need any additional attribute on the select. All you need to do is to make sure that the ng-model expression references the option you want to select. For example, in your controller:

```
$scope.selectedAttribute.GC = $scope.tableColumns[0];
```

ngModel creates a 2-way binding:

- you select an option, and $scope.selectedAttribute.GC is set to the selected item
- you set the value of $scope.selectedAttribute.GC to one of the options, and that option becomes the selected one

Comment: selectedAttribute.GC in the text area has the value in it. but still not selecting.

Comment: The ngModel of the select references an element from $scope.tableColumns. This element is an object, not a string. The model of a text area is a string. So the model of the textarea can't be any of the elements of $scope.tableColumns.